# Hide and Show winform TableLayout Row through C#

Tags: c#, winforms

[screen2_Mar31.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvGgh.png) [Screen3_Mar31.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgrwN.jpg) I have designed TableLayout Panel with 4 rows as first row always to be visible whereas last row exists with "Add" linklabel the inbetween rows need to be kept hidden, when the user hits "Add" button it needs to show the hidden rows sequentially for the first click 1,2, 4 th row to be shown and for the second click rows 1,2,3 to be visible and row 4 ( which contains "Add" to be hidden )

but i have seen that the controls designed in the second row and third row moves to 4th row while hiding those rows,

please help me to fix the above,
thanks in advance,

```
private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < tableLayoutPanel15.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        if (tableLayoutPanel15.RowStyles[i].Height == 0)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                tableLayoutPanel15.RowStyles[i - 1] = new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50f);
                tableLayoutPanel15.RowStyles[i] = new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50f);
                cmb_DrawnBy2.Visible = true;
                cmb_percentageBy2.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                tableLayoutPanel15.RowStyles[i - 2] = new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 33.33f);
                tableLayoutPanel15.RowStyles[i - 1] = new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 33.33f);
                tableLayoutPanel15.RowStyles[i] = new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 33.33f);
                tableLayoutPanel15.RowStyles[i + 1] = new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 0);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

screen1_Mar31.jpg is where i am failing so please help me on that,